# Kivy app on android only loads (3 seconds) and then closes itself

Tags: android, python-3.x, virtual-machine, kivy, buildozer

**SOLVED PROBLEM :**

> I would like to ask about a Kivy-Python app just built using
>   `buildozer` on the Oracle virtual machine. The app is written in
>   Windows, **python 3** using `kivy` and depends on `numpy`, and some
>   `.png` file.
>
> ***Building the apk file :***
>
> On the virtual machine Linux terminal, I have set the project folder
>   that contains the main file `main.py`, and then run:
>
> ```
> buildozer android debug
> ```
>
> the process by this line took quite some time. The apk file has size
>   of 11MB. After I plug in the phone, I ran (on VM Linux terminal):
>
> ```
> buildozer android deploy run
> ```
>
> The app was installed on the phone.
>
> ***The problem :***
>
> But when I open it : *it only says "loading..." alongside with the
>   Kivy logo and then it closes itself.* **What causes this?**
>
> The python that I saw in the VM terminal is `python 2.7.13` while my
>   code was written in `python 3`. **Is this the problem? If it is, what
>   is the solution?**
>
> Hope to get feedbacks on this. Thanks.

**SOLUTION :**

> The solution was to rewrite the code such that it works in `python 2.7`. Now the code works in Python2 and Python3. Then I build the apk using this edited `main.py`. Now, it does not crash.

Comment: you need to get the logcat from your device to see what's causing the crash, it might be that you packaged using the default buildozer configuration, so your code is run by python2 not python3, or it might be something else, but the easiest way to know is to use `buildozer android run logcat` to see the error when the ap crashes.

Comment: @Tshirtman thanks. I had run the `logcat` , its quite a long row of codes..(and there is no ERROR visible) but when i interrupt using ctrl-c, i see in the last lines that it runs some python files <-from the buildozer folder <- from the folder of Python 2. My code is written in python 3. `buildozer` can't package python 3 yet is'nt it..? So a solution may be to rewrite the code so it is compatible in python 2.

Comment: A new issue should be a new question, since the solution you found to the first one may help others in the future. (buildozer can package to python3 btw, you just need to ask it to, and have the crystax NDK installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a regex to filter some logcat's outputs by uncommenting the "android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D" line in the buildozer.specs, (it's just look at log concerning python, but you can add some info to filter more.).

Also I went through similars problems with this configuration (python3 on computer, and python2 on android, and yes, you have to make your code "almost" both compatible).
For that, there are some easy steps to remember (I might forget some):
Add "@static-method" the line before statics methods are defined
Add an empty "__init__.py" file on python subfolders

I doubt it's a problem with numpy recipe, but it can, so you can add the version you want to use in buildozer.specs, or just clean the buildozer to test again.

Hope this help you, let me know :)

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the post... The previous problem is solved, by rewriting the code that works in Python2. I have tried this `logcat` for the new problem, I don't see any error.

Comment: Arf, no able to reproduce, I tried with the default buildozer init, Image widget on the kv file (image on root directory of the project, next to main.py and main.kv, source line is "source: "im.png"  "). Can you send your code to test if it's a code problem or a computer/installation one ? (of course, don't send us all your code, the less is better, until it contain your problem, work on desktop, but not on mobile)